# Changing an existing namespaced attribute with lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an existing XML document and I'd like to change a namespaced attribute to another value.

I have this:

```xml
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="center">
  <ac:rich-text-body>
    <p>
      some text
    </p>
  </ac:rich-text-body>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

I would to turn the above into this:

```xml
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="new_center">
  <ac:rich-text-body>
    <p>
      some text
    </p>
  </ac:rich-text-body>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

This python code:

```
from lxml import etree

pagexml = """<ac:structured-macro ac:name="center"> <ac:rich-text-body> <p> some text </p> </ac:rich-text-body> </ac:structured> -macro>"""
prefix_map = {"ac": "http://www.atlassian.com/schema/confluence/4/ac/",
              "ri": "http://www.atlassian.com/schema/confluence/4/ri/"}
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
root = etree.fromstring(pagexml, parser)

for action, elem in etree.iterwalk(root, events=("end",)):
    if elem.tag == "ac:structured-macro":
        if elem.get("ac:name") == "center":
            elem.set("{ac}name", "new_center")
print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, encoding=str))
```

Produces this:

```xml
<ac:structured-macro xmlns:ns0="ac" ac:name="center" ns0:name="new_center">
  <ac:rich-text-body>
    <p>
      some text
    </p>
  </ac:rich-text-body>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

The `<ac:structured-macro>` could exist anywhere in the XML tree. I know that I could do this with regexes, but I would prefer to do it the correct way as I think that would be more robust. I hope there's somewhere I can pass the `prefix_map` and have it honor the `ac` namespace.

Comment: To be sensible XML, your ‘source’ xml needs to include a definition of the ac namespace like`xlmns:ac=‘...’` - can you edit it to XML which defines the ac namespace URI, and then show the corresponding output from your code? The actual namespace literal ‘ac’ doesn’t matter (its URI is all that matters) so ‘ns0’ is just as valid as long as it’s the same URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with lxml. Here is another solution for your reference only.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc

html = '''
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="center">
    <ac:rich-text-body>
    <p>
      some text
    </p>
  </ac:rich-text-body>
</ac:structured-macro>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
structuredMacro = doc.select('ac:structured-macro')
structuredMacro.setAttr('ac:name', 'new_center')
# Or
# structuredMacro.setAttrs({'ac:name': 'new_center'})

print(doc.html)
```

Result:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="new_center">
    <ac:rich-text-body>
    <p>
      some text
    </p>
  </ac:rich-text-body>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

Comment: This does work for the example I provided. However, the document I'm working with is actually more complicated. `<ac:structured-macro>` can be nested deeply in the document. It looks like `simplified_scrapy` can't deal with that.

Comment: @ChrisW. Of course, here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples